# Where I can see the logs in Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, laravel-5.6

I am new to GAE, and hence this question may be very easy for the experts in GAE.

I have Flexible App Engine, SQL instance of MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7

I have hosted my laravel app on the GAE, and after following the tutorial: [Run Laravel on Google App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)

I am unable to get the first page properly, I am getting 500 Error, my app URL: [Its About Veg](https://itsaboutveg.appspot.com/)

I want to investigate the error, as I can do on my local box, but I am unable to get the proper logs.

I figured it out that it gives 500 Response from the `https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=project-id` URL, but I am unable to get the proper stack trace of the error, the only thing I am getting here is some kind of `JSON` data.

Moreover, I thought to download the log file from the server, so that I can manually check the logs and resolve the issue, but alas! I am unable to find that too.

Can you please help me out in this context.

Comment: downstairs beneath carpet :D

Answer (score 18):

There are a number of methods for retrieving logs from App Engine.

You can try the `gcloud app logs` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/) to retrieve logs for your application. For example to output the logs into your terminal you could run:

```
$ gcloud app logs read
```

Or to stream the logs you can run:

```
$ gcloud app logs tail
```

It's also possible to download the log data from your application to a file on your local computer. If you install [App Engine SDK for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/download) you are able to run the `appcfg.py request_logs` command, which will allow you to download the logs. For instructions on how to do this, I would recommend taking a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/downloading-logs).

You can also perform some fine grained searches using GCPs logging page (there is a method to export download these logs which I will detail below).

Logs in Google Cloud Platform for App Engine, and all other Google Cloud Platform resources can be viewed in Stackdriver Logging.

To navigate to Stackdriver Logging in the Console, navigate to:

> Logging > Logs

Once there, you will find several drop-down menu's. In the first one, you will be able to select the Google Cloud Platform resource you would like to view logs for.

In this drop-down menu, select `GAE Application`. This will ensure the second drop-down menu populates with the names of various logs available for viewing from your GAE Applications. For example, you can specify nginx.error or syslogs in this menu to filter specific logs.

Logs from you applications log files are streamed into Stackdriver logging so they essentially contain the same information as the application logs, albeit in JSON format to ensure they are readable.

Likewise, you can filter the CloudSQL logs. To do this, in the first drop-down menu, select Cloud SQL Database, and specify the database you would like to check.

The other drop-down menu's in the logging view allow you to select various log-levels (for example 'Error', 'Warning', 'Critical' etc) and time settings that allow you to specificity times/dates for finer granularity searches.

You also have the option of typing search strings in the Stackdriver Logging search bar and using them to filter the displayed logs.

If you would like to download these logs, an option would be to create a log sink to Google Cloud Storage. This essentially allows you to write a filter (for the logs you are interested in) and export the logs to Cloud Storage. If required, you would then have the option to download the logs from Cloud Storage.

There is some useful information [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) about setting up a log sink.

Comment: Hi @neilH, I tried `gcloud app log tail`, basically it is the same thing that I am able to view from the console. The thing is, I am not getting the verbose logs like stack trace, to get that, what I need to do?

Comment: Did you try the 2nd suggestion in the post?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing from the starting, I can only see that it gives `500` error, but it got, from where it got, it has nothing in it, this also doesn't come under `error` level? Do I need to do any configuration to see the proper logs?

Comment: Okay, so you installed  App Engine SDK for Python and managed to download the logs using command `appcfg.py request_logs`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I have `PHP` app, why SDK for python is needed? I mean SDK for PHP would be having the same thing that has in Python SDK.

Comment: I've amended the two links in my post to point to the PHP pages.

Comment: @neilH are you saying it's not possible to see stacktraces with `gcloud app logs`?