# Flask app inside Google App Engine responses 502 if request involves db querying

Tags: python, database, flask, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I implemented and tested the project locally with the same data in database as I have in GCP. But when I deploy my project in GCP it returns 502 every time. How can I fix this issue?
app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.9

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

connection to db:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engines = {"rdbms": create_engine('postgresql://<user>:<password>@<public ip of instance>:5432/books_reviews')}
```

P.S. I only started learning GCP, so sorry if this is a stupid question.
P.P.S. Repo url: https://github.com/LilJohny/BookReviewsAPI

Comment: Check the logs for error messages. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093487/8016720

Comment: Hey Denis, a minimal reproducible example would help a lot, but as John said - the logs will most definitely tell you what's happening.

Comment: @jabbson Added repo url. Please check it.

Comment: Also, I ran logs commands, but they just stuck with no output.

Comment: And also in repo there are local database connection credentials, on gcp I use public ip of my sql instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code.

Had to change a few things though, like I

- had to change the runtime to 3.7,
- added network and subnetwork (but this is because I do not have a default network, this may not apply to you)
- added requirements.txt with used modules.

Running the code (got 502) and going over the logs(`gcloud app logs tail`)
I requested /rdbms/reviews/product_id/100) and it revealed the following

```
2021-03-23 13:57:30 default[20210323t103627]  [2021-03-23 13:57:30 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)
2021-03-23 13:57:31 default[20210323t103627]  [2021-03-23 13:57:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

which means that the worker is timing out for the request made, I am not sure if this is what happens to you or not, or probably this is because I do not have anything in the database. Please check the `gcloud app logs tail`, this should give you a hint. Tip: if you see nothing in the output of the command, give it couple of minutes, sometimes it does take a while for the output to be printed.

**UPD:**
I am nearly positive the issue is with the authorized networks. Look under SQL - Connections - then Authorized networks. If no networks are authorized the connection will be refused and timeout will happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for you answer, but can you hint me why this timeout happens? I suppose that there is some permissions problem, but I don’t know which permissions do I need.

Comment: Sure thing, I am nearly positive the issue is with the authorized networks. Look under SQL - Connections - then Authorized networks. If no networks are authorized the connection will be refused and timeout will happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these helped. Probably it would be better if you put your comments in answer. Actually I added network in the instance that was deleted, so I actually had no networks in my current instance.